# z-index having not effect

Tags: html, css, z-index

When trying to position text infront of things using the z-index property, It seems that the z-index has not effect on anything. Here is my code that I am using.

The CSS Code

```
#hero-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
}

#hero-computers {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The HTML Code

```
<div id="hero-content">
    <div id="hero-title">Best Game Servers</div>
    <img id="hero-computers" src="img/hero-computer.png">
</div>
```

Comment: you should be using `hero-title` instead of `hero-content` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try `#hero-computers { z-index: -1; }`
2. Or Try add `#hero-title { z-index: 2; position: relative; }`

Comment: Works great! Thank m8